# Does a nonlinear additive function on R imply a Hamel basis of R?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, real-analysis

A function is additive if $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$.  Intuitively, it might seem that an additive function from R to R must be linear, specifically of the form $f(x) = kx$.  But assuming the axiom of choice, that is wrong, and the proof is rather simple: you just take a Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, and then you define your function f to be different in at least two distinct elements of the basis.

But my question is this: if there is no Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$, then must $f$ be linear?  To put it another way, does ZF + the existence of a nonlinear additive function imply the existence of Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$?

I checked the Consequences of the Axiom of Choice Project, a database of choice axioms and their relationships [here](http://consequences.emich.edu/CONSEQ.HTM), and it said that it didn't know.

Comment: Previously posted on MSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366010

Comment: Since you copy pasted your question (without bothering to reply to my answer or to my comments), I figured I'll copy-paste my answer here as well. In case you happened to have missed it on MSE somehow. 

Comment: Asaf, I'm sorry I didn't respond to you.  I found your answer, giving reasons why you think it's probably an open problem, to be really helpful.  I was just waiting, holding out hope that someone else may be aware of some research that resolved the question.

Comment: Doesn't BPI already imply that there are discontinuous additive functions? (Write down a fragment of the theory of $(\mathbb R, f)$ including statements of the form $f(q)=q$ for all rational $q$, and $f(\pi)=0$, and extend it to a complete theory.) But the basic Cohen model, where BPI holds, certainly has no basis for $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$.  

Comment: Goldstern, I'm not really familiar with the Boolean Prime Ideal theorem and Cohen models, so could you elaborate on your reasoning?

Comment: Goldstern, how can you conclude that there is not Hamel basis?

Comment: Instead of "certainly" I should have written "it seems clear to me, or at least plausible".   I admit I don't have a proof, otherwise I would have written it as an answer. 

Comment: Goldstern, I just checked, and the Consequences of the Axiom of Choice Project searches over the Cohen models and the Fraenkel-Mostowski models, so if any of them had a discontinuous additive function but not a Hamel basis of R, it would have told me.

Comment: @Goldstern: This is a naive question. In your BPI argument, how do you ensure that $f$ is real-valued (rather than having values in some hyperreal field)?

Comment: Goldstern: The Consequences of the Axiom of Choice search lists the question of the implication from BPI to a discontinuous additive function as unknown. I would think that if it weren't hard to clean up your completeness argument, it would be known.

Comment: @AlexanderPruss: You are right, I did not think of the possibility that my f may take infinite values. If I knew that the values of f on R are all finite, I could round them to the next real number without violating additivity.  But I don't think this can be achieved with compactness only, and I don't think there is an  omitting type theorem for uncountable languages.

Comment: If one could show that there is a bounding function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that for any finite-dimensional subspace $S$ of $\mathbb R$ (considered as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$) containing $1$ and $\pi$ (say), there is an additive function $f:S\to\mathbb R$ with $f(1)=1$ and $f(\pi)=0$ and $|f| \le g$ everywhere on $S$, then one could indeed use BPI--or just Hahn-Banach!--to prove that there is such a function on all $\mathbb R$.  This would provide an alternate route to showing that Hahn-Banach implies non-measurable sets. But I don't see how to prove there is such a $g$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To my knowledge this is an open problem.

If one looks at Herrlich **The Axiom of Choice**, there is a diagram (7.23, p. 156) of implications related to non-measurable sets (which include discontinuous solution to the Cauchy functional equation problem), one can see that this is pretty far down below the existence of a Hamel basis.

Had it been known to be equivalent, an arrow back would be there -- and the book is not that old.

I doubt Herrlich would have omitted a reference to such fact, had it been known, and the last time I looked around, I couldn't find anything newer which proved anything related to that (and I did look around several times when answering a couple of questions).